# How to edit lines other than starting from specific character in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a large text file with 40000 lines. The file contains a log from the app, i need to extract specific content or lines from it. For example,

```
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-89
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-89
akfjdsggosvon213340
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-A3-4B-76-89
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-B3-55-6F-8F
jafgwog0';[fkfjs
recieved
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-B3-55-6F-98
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-8D
1-rjj=20`'q.f0f2
```

and So on...
I need to retain the lines starting with character A and B. Is there a way to do it in Notepad++? I request some one to help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^AB].+\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
[^AB]       : Any character that is not A or B
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
\R          : any kind of linebreak
```

- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *Check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

This will remove all lines that don't start with A or B

**Result for given example:**

```
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-89
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-89
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-A3-4B-76-89
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-B3-55-6F-8F
A  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-B3-55-6F-98
B  15.32.154.000  0x 00-01-23-45-67-8D
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, but it still does not clear out all the random lines though. Some part of it is done, but not completely.

Comment: @NithinN:Could you give some examples of lines that don't work?

Comment: Not OP, but 'akfjdsggosvon213340' doesn't work correctly for me with '^[^AB].+\R'.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Have you checked "Match case"?

Comment: No. That got it though. Didn't read carefully enough. =P